# Plotting a transformed distribution as a PDF

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I'm rather new to Mathematica having been a longtime Matlab user, so apologies if my question is framed incorrectly or I have missed out expected infomation. I have tried to distill the problem to the essentials.

Effectively I am trying to plot a a transformed distribution in a similar fashion to this example code:

```
    data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[6, 5/3], 10^6];
    Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"], 
    Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[6, 5/3], x], {x, 0, 14}, 
    PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

I have create a transformed distribution, sampled some data from it using RandomVariate and plotted it in a histogram.

```
    hiod = 6.5/2;
    transDistrib = 
    TransformedDistribution[hiod/Tan[theta*Degree], 
    theta \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[6, 5/3]];
    dataTrans = RandomVariate[transDistrib, 10^6];
    Histogram[dataTrans, {0, 80, 1}, "PDF", ImageSize -> Large ]
```

This works as expected (I have done the same thing in Matlab). However, the equivalent generation of a PDF fails (code just hangs and aborts).

```
    Plot[PDF[transDistrib, x], {x, 0, 80}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

I get the distinct feeling I an making a terribly simple error, either in my basic coding or understanding of how to represent probability distributions in Mathematica.

Ultimately I would like to derive the equation for the transformed distribution, but I have stumbled at this earlier stage using Mathematicas inbuilt functions.

Any pointers to solving my error would be greatly appreciated. I'm using Mathematica 11.0.1 on macOSX Sierra.

Comment: What is `hiod`? Here it is underfined, therefore `TransformedDistribution` also remains unevaluated.

Comment: Ah, sorry, this is an error in my post hiod is defined, and works fine with generating the histogram with the transformed distribution. I'll edit the post to correct this. Generating the PDF still fails though.

Comment: Have edited the post to define hiod. I did this in the code, but made an error in transferring the code to the post. The histogram for the transformed distribution works fine so TransformedDistribution appears to be evaluated fine. The code hangs at the point of generating the PDF.

Comment: Thanks. I did wonder what TransformedDistribution did internally as I could indeed get the exact same result from doing the transform myself. I assumed TransformedDistribution was doing something more clever from the examples in the help text in Mathematica. Deriving the PDF algebraically is indeed the ultimate aim. I was hoping that would come out of TransformedDistribution some way, but it sounds as if I misunderstood.

Comment: You are right, my bad. I suppose Mathematica cannot solve your proposed transformation because of the periodicity of `Tan`.

Comment: @NicholasG, you would use `Exp[x]` as the transform to get a lognormal though.

Comment: @flyingmind, I don't think you misunderstood. Mathematica *will* give you a closed form PDF if it can work it out.

Comment: Ok, I'm wondering if I get get around this with some assumptions. The problem only makes sense with theta < 90 Degrees and theta > 0, and hiod > 0. New to Mathematica so not sure the best way to go about that. I'll have a dig.

Comment: Yes, the periodicity of `Tan` as @NicholasG suggests is an issue.  You don't have a simple one-to-one function.  You should look up "wrapped normal" to see that when you restrict the angles you're feeding to your function to range from say 0 to $\pi$ radians (or 0 to 180 degrees), the resulting density of that random variable has an infinite number of terms.  But because you'll then have a one-to-one  function, you can likely get an algebraic form for the density of the transformed variable but it will almost certainly have an infinite number of terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hiod = 6.5/2;
```

Since the tails of a normal distribution go outside of the allowed range, use [`TruncatedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TruncatedDistribution.html) to constrain the range of `theta`

```
transDistrib = 
  TransformedDistribution[hiod/Tan[theta*Degree], 
   theta \[Distributed] 
    TruncatedDistribution[{0, 90}, NormalDistribution[6, 5/3]]];

dataTrans = RandomVariate[transDistrib, 10^6];

Show[
 Histogram[dataTrans, {0, 80, 1}, "PDF", ImageSize -> Large],
 Plot[PDF[transDistrib, x], {x, 0, 80}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

With a different mean for the underlying `NormalDistribution`,  the bin specification for the `Histogram` must be adjusted.

```
transDistrib = 
  TransformedDistribution[hiod/Tan[theta*Degree], 
   theta \[Distributed] 
    TruncatedDistribution[{0, 90}, NormalDistribution[3, 5/3]]];

dataTrans = RandomVariate[transDistrib, 10^6];

Show[Histogram[dataTrans, {0, 250, 1}, "PDF", ImageSize -> Large], 
 Plot[PDF[transDistrib, x], {x, 0, 250}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work well, but changing the mean of the normal distribution results in the histogram and the pdf giving quite different probabilities.

Comment: `hiod = 6.5/2;
transDistrib = 
  TransformedDistribution[hiod/Tan[theta*Degree], 
   theta \[Distributed] 
    TruncatedDistribution[{0, 90}, NormalDistribution[3, 5/3]]];

dataTrans = RandomVariate[transDistrib, 10^6];

Show[Histogram[dataTrans, {0, 80, 1}, "PDF", ImageSize -> Large], 
 Plot[PDF[transDistrib, x], {x, 0, 80}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]`

Comment: Sorry, pressed enter too soon.... Not suite sure what the difference is here as both are being generated by `transDistrib`.

Comment: @flyingmind - see edit.

Comment: For your update about 5.5% of the data lies above 250 and with the bin specification of `{0,250,1}`, `Histogram` ignores that data and causes the "bars" to show above the PDF of the transformed distribution.  So I'd argue that the apparent lack of fit at the higher probability density values is a bit misleading.  (In other words, your fit is better than it looks.)  The same thing happens with the other histogram but only about 1.4% of the data is above 80 so the lack of fit does not look as bad.

Comment: Great, thanks. This makes sense. I had a play with the bin sizes and range but had increased the range to that extent. I was also misled slightly by the way in which Matlab handles histograms which is different to Mathematica. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: That should have read "... had increased the range to that extent". Thanks again.

Comment: Damn. Long day. That should have read "... had **not** increased the range to that extent". Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

If most (meaning greater than 99.9%) of the probability is between angles of -90 and +90 degrees, then using the standard transformation of a random variable techniques (find inverse function, multiply by Jacobian, etc.) will give an "exact approximate" or "approximately exact" result.  (The exact result requires dealing with a wrapped normal distribution.)

There's no mathematical problem using negative angles and if negative angles are not a problem with your experimental design, the following should work.  The density function of $y=hiod/\tan{(\theta \pi/180)}$ where $\theta \sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ (and $\theta$ is in degrees) can be calculated:

```
μ = 6;
σ = 5/3;
hiod = 13/4;
pdf[y_, hiod_, μ_, σ_] :=
  (2 π σ^2)^(-1/2) Exp[-( (180 ArcCot[y/hiod])/π - μ)^2/(2 σ^2)]*
  180/(hiod π (1 + (y/hiod)^2))
```

We can take some random samples:

```
d = NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]];
z = RandomVariate[d, 10^6];
dataTrans = hiod/Tan[z*Degree];
```

There are many extreme values that make using the defaults for `Histogram` unsatisfactory so we create a custom set of bins:

```
lower = 0;
upper = 85;
bins = {Flatten[{Min[dataTrans], Table[i, {i, lower, upper}], Max[dataTrans]}]};
Show[Histogram[dataTrans, bins, "PDF", ImageSize -> Large,
  PlotRange -> {{lower, upper}, Automatic},
  PlotLabel -> Style["μ = 6", Bold, Large]],
 Plot[pdf[y, hiod, μ, σ], {y, lower, upper}]]
```

[image: Histogram for mean 6]

Below are the figures for `μ=3` and `μ=0` showing the histogram and probability density function:

[image: Histogram for mean 3]

[image: Histogram for mean 0]

Comment: Thanks. This is very nice. I am starting to like Mathematica more and more as I get use to it. I would like to work out the exact symbolic solution so have started to investigate the wrapped normal and the von Mise distributions. For my particular application negative angles would mean the eyes are pointing behind the head, and angles > 90 that the eyes are diverging. So neither is physiologically plausible, but mathematically they are fine. Similarly hoid > 0 else the distance between the eyes is zero.

Comment: Actually hiod < 0 would be a negative distance between the eyes.